# How to return a selection ordered by month and year

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, extract

I'm trying to run a query to select and count rows grouped by their zipcode, month, and year, but I'm having problems with the ordering of the results.  The best I can do is get the results back ordered by year, but the month is ordered alphabetical.

Here is my query

```
SELECT incident_zip, 
   TO_CHAR(created_date,'Mon') AS mon,
   EXTRACT(year FROM created_date) AS yyyy,
   COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM complaints 
WHERE incident_zip 
IN (11209, 11201, 11202, 11203, 11204,
  11205, 11206, 11207, 11208, 11209, 
  11210, 11211, 11212, 11213, 11214, 
  11215, 11216, 11217, 11218, 11219, 
  11220, 11221, 11222, 11223, 11224, 
  11225, 11226, 11228, 11229, 11230, 
  11231, 11232, 11233, 11234, 11235, 
  11236, 11237, 11238, 11239, 11240, 
  11241, 11242, 11243, 11244, 11245, 
  11247, 11248, 11249, 11251, 11252, 
  11254, 11255, 11256) 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 3 ASC;
```

My results are the following,

```
 incident_zip | mon | yyyy | total 
--------------+-----+------+-------
        11201 | Apr | 2010 |    23
        11201 | Aug | 2010 |     2
        11201 | Dec | 2010 |    96
```

Is there a way to extract both the month and the year or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You want to get the month number somehow.  I'm sure postgesql has a function for that.  It might even be the extract one you used to get the year.

Comment: Thanks, @DanBracuk for the advice, and that's what I did with `DATE_TRUNC` thereby getting the month AND the year.

Answer (score 1):

I used `DATE_TRUNC('month', created_date) AS Date`, which returns a sort of "rounded" datetime object. It looks like this, `2010-01-01 00:00:00-05`. Since the datetime object still contains the year I could then order the results by using one less group.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by MM representation of month:

```
... 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, to_char(created_date,'MM')
ORDER BY 1, to_char(created_date,'MM') ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick any date from every group and use it for sorting. For instance, you could sort by `MAX(created_date)`:

```
ORDER BY 1, MAX(created_date)
```